# Find max value from an array of key-value pairs

Tags: php, arrays

How can I find the maximum value, given that I have the following key-value pairs in an array:

```
print_r($TheArray);

Array ( [key1] => 0.258 [key2] => 0 [key3] => 0.31)
```

Comment: Have you tried `echo max($TheArray);` ?

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran, thanks works as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [**`max`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.max.php)

```
print_r(max($TheArray));
```

Or even you can use with `array_keys` like

```
$max = max(array_values($TheArray));
```

Now get the corresponding key with `array_search`

```
$key = array_search($max, $TheArray);
```

Comment: Quick with the answer lol. +1 I did like the example if your original rather than just the edited one.

Answer (score 3):

Use PHP's max() function.

`If the first and only parameter is an array, max() returns the highest value in that array. If at least two parameters are provided, max() returns the biggest of these values.` -- from php.net

Answer (score 2):

You can try this..

```
 Print_r(max($array_value);
 Print_r(min($array_value);
```

Refer URL [Click Here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.max.php)